# hadoop grep command

Tags: hadoop, grep

Can any one tell me what does the following grep command do:

```
 $ bin/hadoop jar hadoop-*-examples.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+'
```

Comment: This is not a Linux grep command, btw.

Answer (score 2):

http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Grep

> Grep example extracts matching strings from text files and counts how many time they occured.
>
> To run the example, type the following command:

```
bin/hadoop org.apache.hadoop.examples.Grep <indir> <outdir> <regex> [<group>]
```

> The command works different than the Unix grep call: it doesn't display the complete matching line, but only the matching string, so in order to display lines matching "foo", use .*foo.* as a regular expression.
>
> The program runs two map/reduce jobs in sequence. The first job counts how many times a matching string occured and the second job sorts matching strings by their frequency and stores the output in a single output file.

Are you asking what the regex itself is? The rest seems straight-forward.

Comment: Also, more specifically, by passing grep argument, it tells the main program from the hadoop-*-examples.jar on what to run (check the manifest file to see what is the main program). There are many other example programs like pi etc.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I haven't run this example and am pulling answering after just looking at http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Grep

The CLI call is: bin/hadoop org.apache.hadoop.examples.Grep    [] and you want to know about .

I suspect this is grouping in regex. (random link - http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util.regex/Group.html)

As noted on the Hadoop Grep link

The command works different than the Unix grep call: it doesn't display the complete matching line, but only the matching string
What I take from this is that if you specify the  value (a number) it will output only the value for that group.

For an example (pulling from the Group link)

input: aba
regex: (a(b)*)+
group 0: aba
group 1: a
group 2: b
If the value for  is 1 then the result would be a. Group 0 is the full match, not the original string, In this case it just happens to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the comments by other people, the command is a little confusing because it doesn't exactly follow the examples.  There is a 'jar' and the name of the jar, and then the 'grep' command, rather than the 'fullpath.Grep'.  It just means that it is looking in that jar for the command.